# Send signal from process to controlling terminal

Tags: bash, c++

I was wondering about a clean elegant way to do the following:
Let's say I have written a C++ program, called `foo`, running inside as part of a shell script, called `bar.sh`. I'd like for the shell script to run `foo` as a background process, and then wait *until* the `foo` execution reaches a line of my choosing, at which point `bar` should continue execution.

For the sake of clarity, here's a dummy example of `bar.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
./foo
wait 
echo "WAKING UP"
```

Here is `foo`:

```
#include <iostream>
 int main(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){
          std::cout << i << std::endl;

          if (i == 50){
              //Wake up bash!
          }
    }
 }
```

I want to modify `foo` and/or `bar` so that the wait command in `bar` will stop when `foo` is at iteration 50 let's say. So when the for loop in `foo` reaches `i = 50`, `bar` should then awaken and print WAKING UP. Of course, `foo` can continue to keep running.

How can I modify these programs to achieve this sort of effect?

Comment: Do you want the script to wait for the *output* "50" or for it to watch the internal state of the program for the value of `i=50`?

Comment: The output of the C program is irrelevant for this example. So to answer your question, I want it to wait/watch the state of the C program until its execution reaches a certain point (which I should be able to control in the source of the C program). I've made a little edit in the C program to make things clearer.

Comment: Have your program send a signal to its parent (eg. `kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1)`) and have that signal trapped in the parent (eg. `trap : USR1`) before starting your program. A trapped signal should cause `wait` to return. This is standard behavior; in `bash` and `dash`, but afaik not in other shells`wait` will also return when a child has "changed status" (ie has stopped or restarted), so you may want to use `wait -f` in `bash`.

Comment: You may also want to check the exit status of `wait`: if it's > 128, then it was interrupted by a trapped signal.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the purpose of `fork()` + `setsid()`.

### bar.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Launching foo"
./foo
echo "Waking up"
```

### foo.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main(int ac, char ** av)
{
    int pid;
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        sleep(1);
    }
    printf("OK, we count to 5.\n");

    /* 
     * Here we fork() + setsid() to detach from parent process
     * Return value of fork is 0 if you are in child, pid of the child 
     * if you're in the parent process 
     */
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        setsid();
        printf("We forked, still running but shell may be back\n");
        sleep(5);
        printf("Exiting ...\n");
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

### Results

```
/tmp/pouet$ ps aux|grep foo
me  8595  0.5  0.1 217548 18576 pts/12   T    14:17   0:01 vim foo.c 
me  9167  0.0  0.0  12716   912 pts/12   S+   14:21   0:00 grep foo
/tmp/pouet$ ./bar.sh 
Launching foo
OK, we count to 5.
We forked, still running but shell may be back
Waking up
/tmp/pouet$ ps aux|grep foo
me  8595  0.5  0.1 217548 18576 pts/12   T    14:17   0:01 vim foo.c 
me  9189  0.0  0.0   4160    76 ?        Ss   14:21   0:00 ./foo 
me  9192  0.0  0.0  12716   940 pts/12   S+   14:21   0:00 grep foo
/tmp/pouet$ Exiting ...

/tmp/pouet$ ps aux|grep foo
me  8595  0.5  0.1 217548 18576 pts/12   T    14:17   0:01 vim foo.c
me  9212  0.0  0.0  12716   908 pts/12   S+   14:21   0:00 grep foo
```

Answer (score 0):

A way would be to `fork` and then leave the parent.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){
        std::cout << i << std::endl;

        if (i == 50){
            if (fork() != 0) {
                _Exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That may have unwanted effects and using `_Exit` is there to avoid the most obvious one.

Another way would be for the C++ program to send a signal to the parent.  This also terminates the wait builtin (I don't remember if it is POSIX or just a bashism).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){
        std::cout << i << std::endl;

        if (i == 50){
            kill(getppid(), SIGINT);
        }
    }
}
```

One thing to pay attention here is the course between the script and the C++ program.  You may want to look at `trap` for a way to handle the signal in the shell script.

Comment: `wait` is a bashism.

Comment: @binarym who told you that?

Comment: Oups... I'm wrong. It's POSIX. Sorry